# Closing emacs in emacs

Tags: emacs

Occasionally when using emacs in `term` mode I will mistakenly run `emacs file` instead of just opening the file. This will create a nested emacs client inside the current client. My problem is how to close the inner client only?

Comment: As a workaround and safeguard, you could have something in your shell init to alias `emacs` to `emacsclient` when you are running inside Emacs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the command `M-x kill-emacs` inside the inner emacs. Backgrounding and killing it works fine but it is a little bit more hackish.

Comment: When I tried it the outer Emacs was intercepting M-x, but if this works for you that's good.

Answer (score 6):

### Answer

You should be able to `C-z` out of it, then kill it with

```
kill %1
```

---

### Explanation

`C-z` will suspend the current process, assigning it a job number and returning you to the shell.

The `jobs` command will show you the current jobs and their numbers. `kill` allows you to kill a process by its job number using the %*n* syntax.

Comment: Clever, I wouldn't have thought of doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the top Emacs. Starts emacs with:

```
emacs --daemon
```

Starts all frame with:

```
emacsclient -c
```

From your term:

```
emacsclient -n
```

Or you should use `eshell` instead.